# Raspberry Pi stuck at black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: boot-issues

After starting pi, the screen gets stuck at blinking cursor at uppermost left side corner. When Ctrl+alt+F2 is presssed the login prompts for very small interval & disappears and this (as shown below) goes on until ctrl+alt+F2 is pressed.

Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 raspberrypi tty2

raspberrypi login:

I am not able to type login and password for. Any solution to make this prompt still so that I can type login and password.

Comment: Try building a rescue system on a new SDCard. Boot that, mount the broken card in a USB reader and repair the damage (which is most likely permissions and ownership of files in /home/pi - specifically things like . Xauthority).

Comment: alternatively, use ssh to do the same - without the faff of purchasing another sd card, imaging it, purchasing a usb sd reader etc etc :p

Comment: I am new to raspberrypi.  Jaromanda X, Can you please elaborate how to use ssh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you MAY have a corrupted build.  I experienced something similar a while back and since I had not fully set up the card, I reloaded the OS and the pi booted up fine.  If you haven't customized the OS yet, it may be easier to reload the OS than taking the time to troubleshoot.

Also, you may want to verify that the card is fully seated and the power supply is functioning properly.  Sometimes, the power management can act 'flaky' if supplied power is out of tolerance.

Comment: Considering how the question is written, it can be anything: corrupted image, defective SD card, screwed up permissions, flaky power, etc. Any guess is as good as the next.

Comment: Thanks for answering. @voyager8  After reloading OS, Raspberry Pi is working fine now.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Located a good quality 5V 2.4A power supply, a good expensive micro USB cable, and same thing.  Rasbian OS splash screen for about 5 seconds, followed by a blinking cursor.  What to do?

Comment: Okay, I have just found out from plugging my microSD card into a Linux machine that the card is just plain corrupted.  But the confusing part is I always shut down my RPi in the correct way (never pulled the power).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was due to full disk space. I deleted some extra large log files in /var/log and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as well and it ended up being low storage space. I don't use Wolfram Engine or Libre Office so I removed them with:

sudo apt-get purge wolfram-engine libreoffice* scratch -y

This freed up about 1200 mbs, and after a quick reboot I was back in.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue when using a display connected via the ribbon cable.  As soon as it has HDMI it boots no problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/121686)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For my case, if I power-cycled the Pi, it worked, if I `sudo reboot`, I would experience the issue.

After some digging on the raspberry pi forums, I found what I think may be the answer:

Here is my ansible task to correct the issue, but basically ensure you have two lines, and don't have a third.

```
    - name: Update boot config
      become: true
      lineinfile:
        path: "/boot/config.txt"
        line: "{{ item.line }}"
        state: "{{ item.state }}"
        create: false
      with_items:
        - line: dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
          state: present
        - line: dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dsi-7inch
          state: present
        - line: display_auto_detect=1
          state: absent
```